# c# email component or code to parse pop 3 (inbox) messages for bounces / non delivery receipts

Tags: c#, email

Anybody have any recommendations?  Any example code online?  I would like to parse undeliverable messages / ndrs.

Answer (score 1):

I've used these sources in the past to create my own pop3 client class:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MailClient.asp
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/pop3client.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/popapp.aspx

Comment: Do you happen to need the ability to parse the inbox messages for ndr's / bounces?  That is the my main reason for accessing the emails in the inbox.

Comment: No I used those samples to simply parse messages for insertion into a database.